# What is the chalk figure in The Rithmatist?

Tags: rithmatist

In Brandon Sanderson's *[The Rithmatist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rithmatist_series)*, the protagonist, Joel, encounters a bizarre two-dimensional figure during his Inception which escapes under the altar without empowering him to be a Rithmatist. At the time, it seemed to be a red herring towards the form of The Scribbler, resembling a man with a bowler hat, but later seems to be something else entirely, as seen in accounts of early Native American drawings, likely tied to early Rithmatists. Has Sanderson provided any additional details? Does this apparition resemble an actual Native American cave drawing that we have some context for (I listened to the audiobook, so I'm afraid I didn't get to see any of the illustrations)?

And yes, I know that there's a planned sequel, *The Aztlanian*, which will likely answer that, but the projected release date isn't until 2017...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The figure was a [shadowblaze](http://coppermind.net/wiki/Shadowblaze).

> A Shadowblaze is a chalk creature that, when bound to a human, bestows Rithmatic powers. They appear to those who become Rithmatists during their inception. Unlike chalklings, Shadowblazes do not need to be affixed to a two-dimensional surface. They have the appearance of primitive cave drawings, and are roughly man-shaped.
>   Discussion of the Shadowblazes' role in the inception ceremony is strictly taboo with non-Rithmatists

Comment: I do remember that term being used now. Thank you.